# Clearing a multiline EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to clear a multiline EditText field inside the OnEditorActionListener.onEditorAction method.

But using any of the obvious ways i.e.

```
((EditText) view).getEditableText().clear();
((EditText) view).getEditableText().clearSpans(); 
((EditText) view).setText("");
```

only clears the visible characters - leaving the the newlines in the field (which then have to be manually deleted).

Is there way to 'completely' clear a multiline EditText field ? (or at least - does anybody know why the above don't work ?)

Comment: Solved (in a minute after a good night's sleep) - the newline was being added after clearing the text because the onEditorAction method implementation was returning false (for other reasons). Returning 'true' indicates that the 'enter' has been processed/consumed and the clear() behaves as expected.

Comment: you should add the above as an answer then accept it, preferably with a nice working code sample :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved (in a minute after a good night's sleep) - the newline was being added after clearing the text because the onEditorAction method implementation was returning `false` (for other reasons).

Returning `true` indicates that the 'enter' has been processed/consumed and the clear() behaves as expected:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view,int actionId,KeyEvent event) {
           post(view.getText().toString());

           ((EditText) view).getEditableText().clear();

           return true;
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an IDE here to test, but you could give it a try:

- `((EditText) view).clearComposingText()`
   It's a inherit method from TextView
- Not so elegant but maybe functional: `setSingleLine =` **true** and then **false** again. Maybe useful until someone can provide something better...

Comment: Out of curiosity (see comment to original question) I tried this but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way with [setMaxLines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29):

```
yourEditText.getEditableText().clear();
yourEditText.setMaxLines(1);
```

Comment: Just for the record (see comment to original question) I tried this but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @tonys: this is strange because it worked for me. I set up a simple activity with an edit text and a button. I started to type some text making the edit text multiline. Then with the button I called the two lines above and the edit text was completely cleared.

Comment: I'm guessing your onEditorAction(...) implementation returned true, in which case getEditableText().clear() works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm feeling a bit too lucky but:

```
((EditText) view).setText(null);
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if this works, as the first thing that `setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type, boolean notifyBefore, int oldlen)` (which is eventually called by `setText(CharSequence text)`) does is to check for `null` and replace with an empty `String`. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/TextView.java#2559).  If it does work I'd love to know why.

Comment: hehe :-) Sorry for the juvenile optimism, but sometimes I notice that I'm so busy with finding the "root of the evil" that I simply fail to check the simplest things (which of course almost always is exactly what solves my problem) :-) In this case it wasn't really that easy though (just as @dave.c noted above).

Answer (score 0):

I used this when I had a clear button on my app

```
            Button clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_reading);

            number.setText("");

            }
        });
```